# MongoDB - $subtract is not working in updateMany()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

This one is not working with 0 result found:

```
user.updateMany(
    {
        status: { $in: ["registered", "applied"] },
        createdAt: { $lt: { $subtract: [new Date(), 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7] } }
    }, 
    {
        $set: { status: "rejected"  }   
    }
)
```

This one is working:

```
user.updateMany(
    {
        status: { $in: ["registered", "applied"] },
        createdAt: { $lt: new Date("08/11/2022") }
    }, 
    {
        $set: { status: "rejected"  }   
    }
)
```

What is the issue? Is `$subtract` in find() the reason for not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$subtract`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#-subtract--aggregation-) is an aggregation operator. To use it in the filter/match criteria, you should use with [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator.

```
user.updateMany({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $in: [
          "$status",
          [
            "registered",
            "applied"
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        $lt: [
          "$createdAt",
          {
            $subtract: [
              new Date(),
              604800000  // 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    status: "rejected"
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e1n99uWfcXb)